# Sequelize map model to existing class that already extends a base class

Tags: class, sequelize.js

I may be missing something obvious but in the following (using [MDN class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) examples) how can the Dog class, which already extends Animal, map/relate to the sequelize model such that I can create a new instance of Dog and save it to the database? I was expecting similar to how SQLAlchemy handles mapping with [map_imperatively()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#imperative-mapping)

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} makes a noise.`);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} barks.`);
  }
}

let d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak();

const DogModel = sequelize.define('Dog', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

Comment: At least a base class should be derived from `Model` class.

Comment: @Anatoly The question is precisely about how *not* to do that. Why should my business class be aware of which database library I'm using?